# Ruby CSV 'illegal quoting' even though quotes are escaped

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm parsing a tab-delimited file using FasterCSV:

```
  csv_rows = FasterCSV.readlines(file_location, {:col_sep=>"\t"})
```

When I parse this I get an 'Illegal quoting on line 1.' error. The line contains this text:

```
...around \"foo bar\" with...
```

Is there another way to escape quotes that might work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another way to escape quotes that might work?

"...around ""foo bar"" with..."

Answer (score 0):

I think the regular CSV class would accept that, incidentally.